# Equivalent of vim mksession on emacs

Tags: emacs, editor, text-editor

I started working on vim about a year ago, and decided to try out emacs.
I really like it so far but there is a functionnality I'm missing on emacs : the ability to save your session as it is right now (the different buffers and local commands, aliases, etc) and reopen it later.

In vim, it takes a simple `:mksession session.vim` and `:source session.vim`

How can I find the same behaviour in emacs?

Comment: The `desktop` library is described in the [Saving Emacs Sessions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) section of the manual, though it works differently - there seems to be no direct command to load a specific desktop file; you'd have to use `desktop-change-dir` and then `desktop-read`.

Comment: @legoscia It feels a bit clunky right now but it seems to work. Thank you